# Obi Wan Bird In Angry Birds Star Wars Force Blast

Tags: angry-birds, angry-birds-star-wars

In Angry Birds Star Wars, the Obi Wan Bird does a directional force blast. My question is, does the force blast actually directly damage the stuff it is pointed at, or is its job to fling debris at the pigs? Also, does it matter how close I am to the debris when I activate said force blast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closeness to the blast directly affects how far things are flung.  It does damage to the objects hit by the force blast, but steel blocks are somewhat resistant.  Ice and Wood blocks are generally damaged or destroyed based on distance from the blast.

Answer (score 2):

[**Black Bird: Obi-Wan Kenobi**](http://angrybirds.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Characters)

> No longer being able to explode, Bomb is now given the power of the
>   "Force", which allows him to use telekinesis to launch blocks and
>   debris at enemies. Later on, this ability is upgraded, allowing Bomb
>   to throw objects further.

He can use the Light Side of the Force to **push nearby blocks away** and towards surrounding Pigs, giving **no direct damage** to the pigs.

Also the Force as a range, the **closer you are to the target stronger the force will be**.